# Swift iOS14 Animate Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints

I'm trying to animate the bottom constraint of a view so it slides up.

This is what I'm doing but it just jumps instantly to the new position, it does not slide:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    self.pickerBottomConstraint.constant += 300
    self.agePicker.setNeedsLayout()
    self.agePicker.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Does anyone know how you can animate constraints in iOS14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
self.pickerBottomConstraint.constant += 300 // this should be outside of animate
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { 
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()  // this should be called for at least the direct parent of the animated picker 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!